# Linux simple while loop

Tags: while-loop, sh, ksh

I have log file keep updating for 30 minutes and I implement script which will check that log file till it has "success" message written in it.So far I have implemented below.Any help or correction would be appreciated.

```
  while [ "($cat R12TECH2.log | grep 'success')" != " " ]
  do
         echo "Please wait...devccm Adautoconfig is still running..."
         sleep 5
  done

          echo "Status of devccm adautoconfig"
          cat R12TECH2.log | grep 'success'
  exit
```

Comment: To simplify, replace `while [ "($cat R12TECH2.log | grep 'success')" != " " ]` with `while ! grep -q 'success' R12TECH2.log`.  If your code is running successfully, StackOverflow is not the right place to ask for advice.  You might try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: As listed, this won't work.  `($cat ...` should read `$(cat ...`, but as @john1024 it's better to get rid of the command substitution `$( ... )` entirely.

Comment: How large is this file? Is it expected to only contain that one line? How is the log file produced? Do you control that process in any way?

Comment: Can you call `adautoconfig` from a shell and look at the log when that is finished?

Comment: Yes, I can execute R12.2 adautoconfig from application shell and can verify it's logs as well. @walter A

Comment: while ! grep -q 'success' R12TECH2.log worked for me @John1024

Comment: When John's answer works, you can accept his answer. Other people will see that you have been given a good answer and he gets a small but precious award.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while [ "($cat R12TECH2.log | grep 'success')" != " " ]
```

With:

```
while ! grep -q 'success' R12TECH2.log
```

The `while` statement does not require a `[...]` statement. It will work with any command that provides a satisfactory exit code.  `grep` is one such command. Since we don't care about the output of the `grep` command, we use `-q` to silence it.

#### Grep and exit codes

Consider the test file:

```
$ cat R12TECH2.log
line 1
success
line 3
```

This `grep` command returns success (0):

```
$ grep -q 'success' R12TECH2.log; echo code=$?
code=0
```

We, however, want the `while` loop to run only if `success` is not in the file.  Thus, provide a leading `!` which tells the shell to negate the exit code:

```
$ ! grep -q 'success' R12TECH2.log; echo code=$?
code=1
```